# quickfixj with IntelliJ - omitted for conflict with (maven errors)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, quickfixj

I cloned `https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj.git` and imported to IntelliJ but maven is showing lots of conflicts (For Example: omitted for conflict with 1.5.15).

This does seem to work in Terminal `mvn -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests=true clean install` but the errors still appear on Maven projects

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me. Check with different Maven version in IDE Maven settings. Try re-importing the project in Maven project tool window. Btw can you build it from IDE (Build | Build Project) and from Maven?

Comment: plexus-util1.0.4 has been overridden by 1.5.15 which is mentioned 3-4 lines above that. you get a similar kind of output when you show the dependencies tree in maven. Idea is just giving you warning about this, assuming that this could be an oversight. You can change the warning setting to just info in idea inspection profile.

Comment: Andrey -  I tried bundled maven 2 and 3 but still the same errors, which maven did you use? or may be send me the steps of how you imported the project as well. Build seems to be failing with a few of these errors
Error:(70, 59) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)